# Date Time is not accurate according to current timezone in PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime, timer

I need to set timezone in my laravel project but it's not giving exact same time. There is a difference in current time (checking via google) and the time my code is showing. My code is below:

```
date_default_timezone_set($generalSettings[0]->timeZone);
// $generalSettings[0]->timeZone = "America/Denver"
echo date("Y-m-d h:m:s");
exit;
```

It's showing "2016-12-21 01:12:05" while current time in "Time in Denver, CO, USA" 1:40 A.M. What I'm missing here that should display exactly same date time. Thanks!

Comment: `Y-m-d h:m:s` `m` is month number; `i` is minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set your default timezone php function, so if yours is Denver you have something like :

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');
$date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
echo $date;
```

Hope it helps you, anyway check it out :

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php)

Edit : If you want it on server have to work on : php.ini

Answer (score -1):

You should change Time Zone on yours server.

Comment: I've to set dynamically as this field is set by users according to their timezones, How can I set timezone of server via program?

Comment: Solution given by @teshtek worked for me as I don't want to play with the server time by changing it otherwise your answer was also correct. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score -1):

Is the timezone of your system correctly set? If yes, try to set it again or use an other NTP server

How to set timezone with Linux (tried on Ubuntu Server):

```
dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

Comment: Can't I do this without interfering in server settings by just using PHP code? This filed will be set by users according to their timezones and I think if I set timezone of server it will effect time of other users too.

Comment: @ÛmÄîrMÄlîk do you want the users to be able to set their own timezone?